# Which directory/folder should I upload my index.html (homae page) in?

Tags: root, cpanel, publish, public-html

this picture features the cpanel of the website I own. Check the image carefully and you will find out that there's "nothing" to be shown in "public_html" folder. But when ever I visit my domain (www.tumajnuri.com) I see the advertising banner of the service I bought the domain from. As an amateur,  this is the first time I decide to upload web pages. I already learned this fact that "public_html" is the default "root" folder of many domains, but nothing exists within this folder. I should find out which folder contains this "jpg" file so, I can delete and replace it with my index.html. Thanks!
My cpanel: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8826319

Answer (score 0):

The default that you can upload/change is the public_html/index.html.

If you do not upload anything there is an other default that you can not change.
It is the domain/hosting service's html.

Comment: But once I tried to upload "index.html" from my computer to "public_html", It wasn't viewable unless on "tumajnuri.com/index".

Comment: If you upload an index.html into the public_html you should see it on your domain. But when you visit yourdomain.com/index it means you want to see public_html/index/index.html. If you want to write the exact url you should use the file extension too. Yourdomain.com/index.html

Comment: After uploading any pages named "index.html" into "public_html" , when I visit my domain (www.tumajnuri.com) I still see that default advertising billboard I purchased the domain from. Do you think I have to edit/fix the "htacces" ?